# How to configure custom rules in SonarQube for javascript

Tags: sonarqube

The sonar which we are using for javascript, there is no way to configure the custom rules in it. There are many links which are showing that it could be configure but when I am trying to find out the same things in our dashboard, they are no available. I am still searching on it. If any one can help, please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of SonarQube are you running? When you talk about custom rules, what are you talking about? Please provide screenshots. Thank you.

Comment: I am using sonar 4.5 @DavidRACODON

Comment: Yep but without further details and screenshots, I'm afraid I can't help you as I don't really understand your issue.

Comment: @DavidRACODON Thanks for your concern. I was able to solve it with help of some other blog in which it says the UI has changed from 4.4 and above. So my problem was solved. Thanks once again.